# SSL connect error when to try add flathub repo

Tags: flatpak

I'm trying to add the flatpak repository with this command:
`sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`

But I'm getting this error:

`error: Can't load uri https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo: While fetching https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo: [35] SSL connect error`

How can I fix this? (Tried reinstalling flatpak and ca-certificates but it doesn't seem to work)

Answer (score 0):

Listen bub, it looks like ya got a little snag in yer giddy-up when it comes to adding the Flathub repo. Now, I got a couple of suggestions for ya, so listen up.

## Bad internet connection

#1 Your internet connection is down or experiencing connectivity issues. You can check your internet connection by visiting a website or pinging a website in a terminal.

## Firewall/Proxy

#2 There's a firewall or proxy blocking your connection to the Flathub repository. If you are behind a firewall or using a proxy, you may need to configure your system to allow connections to Flathub.

## Bad SSL cetificate

#3 Your system's SSL certificate store is outdated or missing a required certificate. You can try updating the SSL certificates on your system using the appropriate command for your operating system.

## Flathub repo down?

#4 There is a problem with the Flathub repository itself. In this case, you may need to wait a while and try again later, or you can try a different repository.

I hope that helped.

Comment: i'm from iran and isp block alot of website but actually i can download flathub repo from firefox and that link is not block. i did not use a firewall or proxy right now and actually i will try to install gepho vpn from .flatpak file but i see that error every time. i try to reinstall SSL cetificate but not work to.i'm wonder how i can solve that and install gephovpn from local flatpak file

Comment: Maybe try installing flatpak this way:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable`

Dont forget to `sudo apt update afterwards`, then `sudo apt install flatpak`.

If nothing helps, you can try using a distro like linux mint or fedora that already have flatpak installed. It sounds reasonable to assume that your isp blocks that traffic.